# React-router + Auth0 login callback not being recognized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, auth0

I'm currently trying to integrate Auth0's custom login form as shown on their website [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/02-custom-login). On successful sign on I get a access token in my url yet the parseAuthHash method is never called.

```
localhost:8080/#access_token=xxx&id_token=xxx
```

My router looks like this.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Landing}/>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} auth={auth}/>
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
            <Route path="access_token=:token" onEnter={parseAuthHash} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
app);
```

I found one way of solving the problem and that involved manually parsing the url on page load, which is something I don't want to have to do.

Comment: Can you confirm if the `parseAuthHash` never gets called (pointing to React not triggering the associated route) or it gets called but does not work?

Comment: I'm also seeing this - an alert dialog set within the parseAuthHash function is not invoked -- though the URL parameters contain the access token and id token populated post-authentication